# How to get the html source of a page correct?

Tags: php

I use this code to get an HTML source:

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$html = file_get_html("http://www.google.com/");
echo $html;
```

But when I want to get the source from [here](http://www.beytoote.com/) I don't correct response and I get something like these characters:

```
���moY�&�9����i�[S$%ٲ�9������l�l/���F"H�H�VDPJ����˲59��[��v���R�Vɖ3KY��_A����_�  ��so�1�N��T�E"#nܸ��s��=�  ��������?�?�������  ���|������0Vk��Z�2o��E۪  ү�XF�ny���;v�R�ܦ���F�Ƨe˷  ��g����{�������}
```

Comment: is utf-8 the right encoding for the language on that site?

Comment: Server return probably gziped data, try this : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php

Comment: Download the content with cURL instead and use `str_get_html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content from Google by default uses some sort of HTTP compression. Two commonly used compression schemas are `gzip` and `deflate`. Read more about it here:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression